# How do I get the "referenced libraries" folder back In the eclipse sdk?

Tags: eclipse

I use the eclipse Ganymede sdk for developing Java apps.
I'm having a strange Issue.

Everything was working fine until recently where the "referenced Libraries " folder went missing from the explorer.

I used to upload the jar's I need Into the workspace. I uploaded the jars In a folder named "lib" and after refreshing the project folder In eclipse that folder "lib" containing the Jar appears.
Now,the Issue arises,when I right click on the jar and select "add to path" the jar Instead of appearing In the "referenced libraries" folder just disappears.
Note:the referenced Library was never there In the first place,I need to find a way to get the folder back.

here's a snapshot of my eclipse framework :  http://www.flickr.com/photos/38561743@N03/4122304046/sizes/o/

Comment: Why is this stopping you from doing what you need to do? Not seeing the referenced libraries shouldn't be stopping you from doing anything.

Comment: It actually Is,I cant compile the code,It gives me an error : http://www.flickr.com/photos/38561743@N03/4122304046/sizes/o/

What I actually want to do Is right click on the jar in the "lib" folder and select the option "add to path" on doing so the jar goes away from the "lib" folder and comes under the "referenced libraries" folder,whenever this used to happen,the code worked well and everything was rosy but recently I cant see the referenced libraries folder and thus on selecting "add to path"  does not bring the jar under the "referenced libraries" section simply because Its not there.
thx

Comment: Hi,
I use the acm library so this shouldn't be the Issue.
I'v compiled the same piece of code many times before this Issue arised and every time the jar got transferred to the  "referenced libraries" and the code worked.
Its not working only after the referenced libraries went missing.
any more leads?
thanks,

Answer (score 14):

The root - Referenced Libraries - of the lib jar disappear if you open J2EE perspective, leaving all the jar in the main project root folder. This is very annoying so,  Please change e perspective from J2EE to Java.

Answer (score 9):

Did you uncheck the *Show 'Referenced Libraries' Node* (accessible through the menu for Package Explorer: the small triangle in the explorer’s title bar)?

(EDIT: The OP provided a screen shot showing that *Show 'Referenced Libraries' Node* is checked in comment to this answer. He confirmed that libraries are not filtered too in a comment to another answer. So, actually, I don't know what is happening here. Strangely, I can't see the "*JRE System Library*" neither and this seems weird. So something must be wrong indeed, but I don't know what. This is not really a good solution but if you can't solve it, maybe consider reinstalling Eclipse.)

Comment: Hi,
I'v check out the view menu section.
the "show reference libraries" were ticked.

But It still doesn't work,the referenced libraries are still missing from the explorer.

heres the screenshot : http://www.flickr.com/photos/38561743@N03/4122829868/sizes/o/

please,can you help,Its really annoying,I want to get to my coding as soon as possible and this little thing Is really getting to my head.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Usually JavaEE is the default perspective.
Change it to Java perspective from

```
Window -> Open Perspective -> Java
```

This should solve the problem.

You can make Java as the default perspective

```
Window -> Preferences -> General -> Perspectives
```

So next time when you open another workspace, Java will be the default perspective and you won't be surprised that the *Referenced Libraries* has disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Please post the contents of your `.project` and more importantly of the `.classpath` files. They're located in the root of your project, but hidden. Use either Windows Explorer or the Eclipse *Navigator* view to see them.

The `.classpath` should contain an entry like the following:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
```

For libraries, the `.claspath` file should contain entries like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/somelib.jar"/>
```

Comment: can you give a bit more details on how to see them?
I don't know how to use the eclipse navigator as well as the Windows explorer to view them.
can you help?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Same issue I had where Reference library does not appear. Close the package explorer and reopen again , it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple:

Firstly make sure that Show 'Referenced Libraries' Node is checked. This can be found by clicking the down arrow in the Package Explorer.

Then, what you probably want to do is ensure all the dependent libraries are in the classpath.
If its a Maven project simply right-click the project, Properties, then under the Libraries tab 'Add variable'. Then navigate (and select) to one of the dependencies using the M2_REPO variable.

You should see the Referenced Libraries come up.
All you have to do from here is make sure each classpath entry (type "var") you need is present in the .classpath file.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you are in the Java perspective and opened your project in project explorer view you wouldn't get what you need. you need to be in the package explorer view to get the Referenced Libraries.

Window --> Show View --> Package Explorer

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've accidentally enabled a filter on the explorer view. Bring up the "view menu" item (the downward-pointing arrow at the top right of the explorer pane), pick "filters", and make sure "libraries from external" and/or "libraries from project" is not selected.

Comment: I'v checked It.
both are unchecked,
heres the screen shot : http://www.flickr.com/photos/38561743@N03/4122057843/sizes/o/

please, can you help ? :(

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that this is because the lib folder is actually empty and there is nothing aded to classpath yet.

This is how you can be sure
1. In package explorer, select "lib" folder and press F5 (refresh). If it doesn't gets the + sign in front of it, the folder is empty.
2. Right click on "lib" and select "Go Into". If the package explorer gets empty, the folder is empty. Select the back arrow icon from the package explorer view menu to get back.
3. Select "lib" menu and do press "Alt + Enter". You should see a properties dialog. Note the path in front of "Location". Copy it and open this location is windows explorer. You can verify that its actually empty or not.

You will see referenced libraries only when a jar has been added to the build path (I guess you know this already).

Try adding a dummy jar to build patch to see if referenced libraries shows up. You may use the "Add external jar" button on the "Libraries" tab of the "Java Build Patch" dialog for quickly verifying this.

Answer (score 0):

you need change to Package Explorer and check 'show "referenced Libraried" Node'

Answer (score 0):

Change perspective to Java perspective by following below instructions:

Follow this : `Window -> Open Perspective -> Java`

This should solve the problem and put all the Jars back to Referenced Libraries.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you are using Project Explorer rather than Package Explorer. To fix the issue: Window->Show View-> Package Explorer or Alt_Shift+Q,P. 
See if that fixes your problem.